# How to list a VM's network under networkfolder in PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, vmware, system-administration, powercli

I've been trying to get the networks under my `networkfolder` in PowerCLI but I don't know the needed snippet for it.

My relevant code is below:

```
$datacenter = (Get-Datacenter|  Out-GridView -Title 'Choose a datacenter' -PassThru)

$networkFolder = Get-Folder -Location $datacenter -Type Network | Out-GridView -Title "Choose a network category" -PassThru
```

I'm trying to `get-virtualportgroup` under the `$networkfolder` but I cant filter for Location.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to go backwards into this one. Try the following:

```
$networkFolder.ExtensionData.ChildEntity | ForEach-Object {Get-View -Id $_}
```